# What is the whistled tune from American Horror Story?

Tags: american-horror-story

There is a whistled song that plays when Tate's fantasies are introduced in the first season of American Horror Story. It also accompanies the final scenes of the season finale.

It sounds painfully familiar, but I can't place it. What is it?

Comment: I had the exact same question and for some reason, I am thinking this tune has *something* to do with the guards at Auschwitz. I am going to dig further until I find the facts about this tune. It is driving me crazy!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a music id question, which are off-topic here

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you are referring to *[Twisted Nerve](http://www.last.fm/music/Bernard+Herrmann/_/Twisted+Nerve)* by Bernard Herrmann scored for the film of the same name - however, you might know it better from *Kill Bill* (Ellie Driver whistles it).